# Failed to load page on a webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm trying to load a page ([http://m.hotelkramervalencia.com/](http://m.hotelkramervalencia.com)) on a Webview in Android. If I load it with an external app like Chrome or Firefox everything goes fine and it loads completely, but if I do it from a Webview it does not work.
I have enabled the javascript but it's not solving the problem.

Is there anything I've forgotten or any idea of what's happening?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add your code here please?? So that we can help you out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be Sure WebView in XML file width and height is `Match Parent` and check your **INTERNET** .

use like this ......

```
 WebView mWeb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

 mWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

 mWeb.loadUrl("http://m.hotelkramervalencia.com/");
```

[image: output]

enjoy coding ..........

Comment: It was the height, i change to match_parent and it's work fine!

Thank you!